# FTP error "553 Could not create file" in RHEL

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

We need to transfer a file from local machine to remote machine. Remote machines settings are as below:

```
[540607@hsldevoradb ~]$ su - Saphr002
Password:
[Saphr002@hsldevoradb ~]$ pwd
/odi/CSV/in
[Saphr002@hsldevoradb ~]$ ls -ld /odi/CSV/in
drwxrwxr-x. 2 oraedw oedw 4096 Oct 28 18:33 /odi/CSV/in
[Saphr002@hsldevoradb ~]$ groups
Saphr002 oedw
[Saphr002@hsldevoradb ~]$ touch a
[Saphr002@hsldevoradb ~]$ ls
a
```

Here `/odi/CSV/in` is the home directory for the user Saphr002. There is full permission for the directory `/odi/CSV/in` to the user Saphr002 and we are able to create a file inside that directory remotely. But whenever we try to transfer file from `ftp`, it will throw a "553 Could not create file" error.

```
C:\Users\osprbs01>ftp 192.168.5.52
Connected to 192.168.5.52.
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
User (192.168.5.52:(none)): Saphr002
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.

ftp> put test.csv.odt
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
553 Could not create file.
ftp>
```

Kindly help to transfer the file through `ftp`.

Comment: Can you check if SELinux is enforcing with the command 'sestatus'?

If you are attempting to FTP to a user's home directory you most likely do not have the correct SELinux context to create files.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  SELinux is enabled in the remote server

Answer (score 2):

In order for SELinux to allow ftpd to access these files they must have the appropriate context.

The following example is from RHEL.  Your paths, etc may vary:

To find the appropriate content you can use `ls -Zd /var/ftp/pub` (or an appropriate directory configured for ftp).  You should see the SELinux contexts just before the filename.

Example: `drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 /var/ftp/pub`

public_content_t is the appropriate type for ftp content.

You can then use the chcon command with --reference or by specifying the type itself.  
Example:

`chcon -Rt public_content_t /odi/CSV/in` or you can use

`chcon --reference /var/ftp/pub /odi/CSV/in`

Which one you use depends on your SELinux policies.  Once completed, retry your FTP process.